# A* in Javascript (with p5.js) not working

Tags: javascript, processing, a-star, p5.js

I'm writing a pathfinding algorithm for a player located in a 2d array of squares. I want to find the shortest path from a to b and do it efficiently. I was working in java (Processing) before, and my function was working just fine.

```
boolean findPath(PVector down, PVector up, Square[][] board) {
  PVector start = up;
  PVector goal = down;

  ArrayList<Square> closedSet = new ArrayList<Square>();
  ArrayList<Square> openSet = new ArrayList<Square>();

  HashMap<Square, Square> cameFrom = new HashMap<Square, Square>((int)Math.pow(squares, 2));
  HashMap<Square, Float> gScore = new HashMap<Square, Float>((int)Math.pow(squares, 2));
  HashMap<Square, Float> fScore = new HashMap<Square, Float>((int)Math.pow(squares, 2));

  for (int i = 0; i<dungeon.floors.get(currentFloor).numSquares; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<dungeon.floors.get(currentFloor).numSquares; j++) {
      gScore.put(board[i][j], 1000.0);
    }
  }

  gScore.put(board[(int)start.x][(int)start.y], 0.0);
  fScore.put(board[(int)start.x][(int)start.y], heuristic(start, goal));

  openSet.add(board[(int)start.x][(int)start.y]);

  while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {
    Square current = board[(int)start.x][(int)start.y];
    float lowest = 1000;
    for (Square s : openSet) {
      if (fScore.get(s)<lowest) {
        lowest = fScore.get(s);
        current = s;
      }
    }
    if (current.locX == goal.x && current.locY == goal.y) {
      while (cameFrom.containsKey(current)) {
        current = cameFrom.get(current);
      }
      board[(int)start.x][(int)start.y].squareType = -3;
      return true;
    }
    openSet.remove(current);
    closedSet.add(current);
    //neighbors() returns an ArrayList of valid neighbors
    for (Square s : current.neighbors(board)) {
      if (closedSet.contains(s)) {
      } else {

        float tempG = gScore.get(current) + 1;
        if (!openSet.contains(s)) {
          openSet.add(s);
        } 
        if (tempG < gScore.get(s)) {

          cameFrom.put(s, current);
          gScore.put(s, tempG);
          fScore.put(s, gScore.get(s) + heuristic(new PVector(s.locX, s.locY), goal));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

float heuristic(PVector start, PVector goal) {
  return dist(start.x, start.y, goal.x, goal.y);
}
```

But I'm moving the game to Javascript, and I cannot tell where my code is going wrong. It is getting stuck on a square and adding it to the closedSet forever (hundreds of thousands of times). Here is my Javascript code -

```
this.findPath = function(f, _start, _goal) {
      var start = _start;
      var goal = _goal;

      var closedSet = [];
      var openSet = [];

      var squareScores = [];
      var startSquare = (start.x * numSquares) + start.y;

      for (var i = 0; i < numSquares; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < numSquares; j++) {
            squareScores.push(new MapSquare(dungeon.floors[f].board[i][j], 10000, 10000));
         }
      }

      squareScores[startSquare].gScore = 0;
      squareScores[startSquare].fScore = this.heuristic(start, goal);
      openSet.push(squareScores[startSquare]);

      while (openSet.length > 0) {
         var current = squareScores[startSquare];
         var lowest = 9999;
         for (var s = 0; s < squareScores.length; s++) {
            if (squareScores[s].fScore < lowest) {
               lowest = squareScores[s].fScore;
               current = squareScores[s];
            }
         }
         if (current.square.x == goal.x && current.square.y == goal.y) {
             return true;
         }

         openSet.splice(openSet.indexOf(current.square));  
         closedSet.push(current.square);

         var currentNeighbors = current.square.neighbors(dungeon.floors[f].board);
         for (var i = 0; i < currentNeighbors.length; i++) {
            var skip = false;
            for (let c of closedSet) {
               if (c.x == currentNeighbors[i].x && c.y == currentNeighbors[i].y) {
                  skip = true;
               }
            }
            if (skip) {
               continue;
            }
            else {
               var tempG = current.gScore + 1;

               var dontAdd = false;
               for (let o of openSet) {
                  if (o.x == currentNeighbors[i].x && o.y == currentNeighbors[i].y) {
                     dontAdd = true;
                  }
               }
               if (!dontAdd) {
                  openSet.push(currentNeighbors[i]);
               }
               var index = (currentNeighbors[i].x * numSquares) + currentNeighbors[i].y;
               if (tempG < squareScores[index].gScore) {
                  //cameFrom.push(gScore[i]);
                  console.log("update");

                  squareScores[index].gScore = tempG;
                  squareScores[index].fScore = squareScores[index].gScore + this.heuristic(squareScores[index].square.x, squareScores[index].square.y, goal.x, goal.y);
               }
            }
         }
      }
      return false;
   };

   //dist from player to goal
   this.heuristic = function(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) {
      return dist(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2);
   };
```

My Javascript code looks a bit different because I have been trying to fix this for a few days, but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong? If the code needs clarification, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code. That link is about debugging in Processing, but the same ideas apply to JavaScript and P5.js.

Specifically, you need to figure out exactly when the code's execution differs from what you expected it to do.

You can do this by adding `console.log()` statements to figure out the value of variables, which functions are called in what order, whether `if` statements are entered, how many times a loop iterates, etc.

If that doesn't work, you can also step through your code with a debugger. Every browser comes with a JavaScript debugger, which allows you to step through the code and examine the value of every variable. Again, the goal is to figure out exactly when the code does something different from what you expected it to do.

When you get it narrowed down to a few lines, if you still can't figure out how to fix it, then you can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that isolates the problem without all the extra code around it. At that point it'll be much easier to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Trust me I have been degugging it for hours on end (with the google chrome dev console). I have been console.logging the size of the lists, stepping through the code line by line, watching the variables, and the only thing I can seem to find is that the heuristic isn't returning the correct value or something. In my original question the heuristic is being divided by 2, but originally it was just a distance function, I don't understand how that could be wrong unless there are very significant rounding errors. Anyways thanks for the advice!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that the heuristic isn't returning the correct value? Can you put together a [mcve] that shows just the heuristic function using hard-coded values, and what exactly is incorrect about it?

Comment: At the bottom of my code, the function this.heuristic is just returning the distance between two points. But it doesn't return the correct distance sometimes.

Comment: @CadenPopps Can you please be more specific than saying it doesn't return the correct distance sometimes? What does it return instead? What are the parameters in those cases? Create a [mcve] that shows just the distance function returning the wrong thing based on hard-coded values, and we can go from there.